# SONAR quality gates on cross-projects

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, bitbucket, sonarqube5.1

We have set up our branching strategy in Bitbucket in a way that for each release to production we create a new release branch in Bitbucket (User Acceptance Testing and then the  production release is done from this branch). Now for each feature to be developed in that release, we create a new feature branch and to merge the new feature developed from the feature branch to the release branch, we create pull requests.
When the pull request is created from a feature branch, we trigger the build in TeamCity which in turn connects to SonarQube server (Version 5.0.1). Sonar now creates a new project for this pull request (as I have specified sonar.branch property) and we can see the analysis on Sonar dashboard. 
Also on creating of a release branch in Bitbucket and on subsequent merges to release branch (from feature branch), we are triggering the build in Teamcity which connects to the same SonarQube server and creates a new project for this release branch.

Now we need to set up a quality gate in SONARQube that will check for the new blocker, critical and major issues introduced in the feature branch against the release branch. So the baseline for us will always be the release branch. Please note that we will have different projects in SONAR for each feature branch and release branch.

Is it possible to have Sonar Quality gates created on cross-projects? I think the SONARQube version 5.0.1, that we are using, doesn't have the capability - Is that correct? Is it possible in the latest SONAR versions?

Thanks and Regards,
Mitesh

Comment: Branches and other projects are two different things. Version 6 supports the use of branches see [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Branch+Plugin) but you have to pay for it.